# ListIterator - One button for next, one for previous but it takes 2 clicks to move on the list

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio, listiterator

I have a `textview` where I load the 0 value by using `textView.setText(nameofstory.next());`
But when I go into the application and use the buttons to move left and right on the list I need to press it twice to get to the next/previous value
Any help please?

```
private List<String> nameofstory
nameofstorylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameofstory.add("test");
    nameofstory.add("tests");
    nameofstory.add("test1s");
    nameofstory.add("test2s");   
ListIterator<String> nameofstory = nameofstorylist.listIterator();    
textView.setText(nameofstorylist.get(0));      


public void NextButton(View view) {

    if (nameofstory.hasNext()){
        textView.setText(nameofstory.next());
    }


}

public void BackButton(View view) {
    if (nameofstory.hasPrevious()){
        textView.setText(nameofstory.previous());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and make sure that you are not using `onClick` on your layout xml.